# UI Automation :- How to click button using javascript of a screen which is not the main screen (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-ui-automation

want to click a button through javascript for testing purpose. i am able to click the button which is on first page, but dont have idea how to click button on second page which comes after clicking button on first page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a reference to that button on the second page -- so you repeat the process from the first page.  Probably, you did something like this (this code is from my app using a tab bar controller):

```
 // Now tap the add button
 var navBar = mainWindow.navigationBar();
 navBar.buttons()["Add"].tap();

 // Now the app loads a new page
 // Get the nav bar again (it would have changed after the tap above)
 navBar = mainWindow.navigationBar();
```

So, the answer is easy -- just call back to the same functions, they will return whatever's on screen at the moment.

Comment: Thaks alot for the answer. will get back to you once i tried the above process.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to ensure that the button is accessable. Either set the Accessability property in Interface Builder (Identity Inspector - last Tab) and give the button an appropriate Accessability Label. If you don't use Interface Builder you can set the property on the button programaticaly.

Now in the script you can call

```
mainWindow.buttons()["name of the accessability label"].tap();
```

mainwindow is:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var application = target.frontMostApp();
var mainWindow = application.mainWindow();
```

Make also sure that the button is visible. The button has to be the deepest element in the view hierarchie which is marked accessable. If the view containing the button is enabled as accessable, it would hide the accessability of the button (which is a subview).

You can log all visible elements in the screen by

```
mainwindow.logElementTree();
```

Moreover, you always can use one single script. The mainWindow.elements() references the view which is shown at a certain moment.

Comment: difference in spelling of mainWindow. "W".